# Writing Bengali in latex

Tags: expl3

I'm new comer in this community. When i'm going to compile this,
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{ভূমিকা}
এটি একটি ইংরেজি লেখা ছোট অধ্যায় যে বাঙ্গালী এ \textenglish{Google Translate} দ্বারা অনুবাদ করা হয়েছে. এটা খুব স্পষ্ট নয় যদি সঠিক অনুবাদ বা না কিন্তু ক্রিয়াটি ফন্ট দেখাতে যথেষ্ট হওয়া উচিত.
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Following message is showing. Few months ago that did not happen.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(D:/Latex/ben.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\polyglossia\polyglossia.sty"
(D:/Latex\etoolbox.sty) (D:/Latex\makecmds.sty)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
(D:/Latex\expl3.sty
(C:\Users\kausani\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3names.sty
*****************************************************************
** 
** Package l3names is obsolete and has been removed!
** 
** Its functionality is now only provided as part of the expl3 package.
** 
** After showing you an error message you can hit <return> we will continue
** for now by loading expl3 for you. However, the old packages will be
** removed entirely at the end of 2017.
** 
** Therefore, please replace '\usepackage{l3names}'
** with '\usepackage{expl3}' in your documents as soon as possible.
** 
*******************************************************************

! Package l3names Error: This package is obsolete --- use 'expl3' instead.

See the l3names package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.45   \@ehc

? 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

What have I to do?

Comment: welcome to the site, you can mark code sections by highlighting and using the `{}` button in the editor (or control-k), I did it this time:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
(D:/Latex\expl3.sty
```

You are pulling most of your packages from the standard miktex place but you have an old local copy of `expl3` in `D:/Latex\expl3.sty` you want to remove (or move) that copy and let latex find the current copy of `expl3` from the standard miktex input  tree.

(You are also getting `etoolbox` and some other packages from `d:\latex` which would be better if they came from the standard input path so that you get the current versions)